# Why does the program that uses a thread takes more time?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I added a thread to count the 3's of the first array while the main process generates the second array. I thought that would make the program faster but after using the time command on Linux, the one with a thread took 0m7.627s and the other one took 0m5.701s.
At first I thought I was using a very small length and it was just greater because of time of the creation of the thread, but it wasn't. The time difference is proportional to the length... 
Does this just work with more threads? (in a different example maybe)
Am I doing something wrong? 
Also I don't understand how the second argument of pthread_join(..., this) works, I've tried in many different ways and it never works. I little help would be awesome, thank you.

Without threads:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define LENGTH 100000000

void * count3s(void * i){
    int numberOf3 = 0;  
    int * j = (int *) i;
    int counter = 0;
    for(counter = 0; counter < LENGTH; counter++){
        if(*(j+counter) == 3){
            numberOf3++;
        }
    }
    *((int *) i) = numberOf3;
    return i;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    pthread_t p0, p1;
    int * i = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*LENGTH);
    int * j = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*LENGTH);
    int c = 0, d = 0;
    srand(0);
    for(c=0;c<LENGTH;c++){
        *(i+c) = rand() % 4;
    }

    for(c=0;c<LENGTH;c++){
        *(j+c) = rand() % 4;
    }

    d = *((int *) count3s((void *) i));
    c = *((int *) count3s((void *) j));
    printf("C:%d, D:%d\n", c, *i);
    return 0;
}
```

With threads:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define LENGTH 100000000

void * count3s(void * i){
    int numberOf3 = 0;  
    int * j = (int *) i;
    int counter = 0;
    for(counter = 0; counter < LENGTH; counter++){
        if(*(j+counter) == 3){
            numberOf3++;
        }
    }
    *((int *) i) = numberOf3;
    return i;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    pthread_t p0, p1;
    int * i = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*LENGTH);
    int * j = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*LENGTH);
    int c = 0, d = 0;
    srand(0);
    for(c=0;c<LENGTH;c++){
        *(i+c) = rand() % 4;
    }
    //thread starts counting 3's
    pthread_create(&p0, NULL, count3s,(void *)i);       //thread created
    for(c=0;c<LENGTH;c++){
        *(j+c) = rand() % 4;
    }

    pthread_join(p0, NULL);     
    c = *((int *) count3s((void *) j));
    printf("C:%d, D:%d\n", c, *i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try moving your `pthread_join` call below the second `count3s` call.  As it stands you are forcing the first count to be finished before the second count starts.  You can also move the first random generation loop into the thread as well, so that both the generation and counting can run in parallel.

Comment: I tried your first suggestion, nothing changed. I don't understand the second one? Wouldn't it be a segmentation fault error? EDIT: Just tried the second one + the first one, made it worse, now it takes 10 secs. I think it waits for the other one to complete. But thanks for helping. Any ideas?

Comment: I can't reproduce the results. On my machine there is no measurable difference.

Comment: How many times did you measure the execution time?  You should measure several times to reduce the chance that the operating system interrupting your execution for more important tasks is skewing your results.

Comment: I did many, greeny, it always the same. Timo try increasing the length maybe or do what Nathan said... It might be a problem of my computer. I doubt it, though.

Comment: Moving the `pthread_join` call after the call to `count3s` will definitely make a difference. Are you running this in a debugger, or in release mode without a debugger attached? If you have a debugger attached, your timings are going to be skewed. As an aside, you might consider adding a few more unnecessary casts to and from `void *`. Those always speed things up, right?

Answer (score 0):

Because creating a thread is not free

Comment: @SadSeven - That does not make any sense.

Comment: I know lol... but with smaller LENGTHS it doesn't even take a second, now it is taking about 4 secs.

Comment: What is the processor(s) up to? Use the debugger

Comment: Probably it's just using a single core for all of the processing. You have shared variables involved here with the int pointer. Perhaps if you were to generate all of it at once, and then do the counting in seperate threads that would show a difference? Having tried it myself I notice a bit more than 1 second decrease in processing time.

Answer (score 0):

If you modify main to generate all of the random numbers at once, then process each array
separately you will see an improvement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define LENGTH 100000000

void * count3s(void * i){
   int numberOf3 = 0;
   int * j = (int *) i;
   int counter = 0;
   for(counter = 0; counter < LENGTH; counter++){
      if(*(j+counter) == 3){
         numberOf3++;
      }
   }
   *((int *) i) = numberOf3;
   return i;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   pthread_t p0, p1;
   int * i = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*LENGTH);
   int * j = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*LENGTH);
   int c = 0, d = 0;
   srand(0);
   for(c=0;c<LENGTH;c++){
      *(i+c) = rand() % 4;
      *(j+c) = rand() % 4;
   }
   //thread starts counting 3's
   pthread_create(&p1, NULL, count3s,(void *)j);
   pthread_create(&p0, NULL, count3s,(void *)i);       //thread created

   pthread_join(p1, NULL);
   pthread_join(p0, NULL);
   printf("C:%d, D:%d\n", *j, *i);
   return 0;
}
```

This gives me the result of
new result:

```
threads
C:24999967, D:24998864

real    0m2.994s
user    0m3.064s
sys     0m0.452s

threadless
C:24996371, D:25002460

real    0m3.510s
user    0m3.196s
sys     0m0.300s
```

It's a small improvement, but it IS an improvement.

Previous result:

```
threads-wrong
C:24996371, D:25002460

real    0m3.840s
user    0m4.032s
sys     0m0.328s
threadless
C:24996371, D:25002460

real    0m3.518s
user    0m3.148s
sys     0m0.356s
```